# JavaScript Loop to decrement element in last index of Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

```
Array = [ 1, 3, 7, 2 ]

1st Iteration = [ 1, 3, 7, 1 ]
2nd Iteration = [ 1, 3, 7, 0 ]
3rd Iteration = [ 1, 3, 6 ]
4th Iteration = [ 1, 3, 5 ]
```

So on & so forth...

Final Iteration should be an empty `[]`

I'm wanting to create a loop that takes the last index & decrements the value by 1 on each iteration. When the value in the last index = 0 it should pop it...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We can use a `while` to do this. Have you tried anything?

Comment: What is the reason for this? We will have an empty array output no matter the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use while and Array.prototype.pop().

```js
function solution(array) {
  while (array.length !== 0) {
    while (array[array.length - 1] >= 1) {
      array[array.length - 1] -= 1;
      console.log(array);
    }
    array.pop();
    console.log(array);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you out.

```js
const decrementLastIndex = (array) => {
    let newArray = [];
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        newArray.push(array[i]);
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is one way of achieving that!**

```
function decrementElement(array){
  while(array?.length !== 0){
    let size = array.length;
    let lastIndex = size - 1;
    if(array[lastIndex] > 0) {
       array[lastIndex] -= 1; 
    } else {
       array.pop();
    }
//printing the array
    console.log(array);
  }
};
```

I hope it helps :)
Reply to this if you need more help or have any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a recursive approach and check the last item first.

```js
function dec(array) {
    if (!array.at(-1)) array.pop();
    else array[array.length - 1]--;
    console.log(...array);
    if (array.length) return dec(array);
}

dec([1, 3, 7, 2]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```